# How can I get the current type from a static method in abstract class?

Tags: c#, static, attributes, types

How can I get the current `Type` in a static method that is defined in an abstract class?

Please note that as the method is defined in an abstract class, I can't use `typeof`.

Why would I want to do this? A possible usage is attributes. Consider the following example:

```
[Identifier(1000)]
public class Rock : Entity { }

public abstract class Entity
{
    public static ushort Identifier
    {
        get
        {
            // How do I get here the current type of the object?
            Type currentType = ...;

            // in a non-static method or property, I'd do:
            // Type currentType = this.GetType();

            foreach (IdentifierAttribute attribute in currentType.GetCustomAttributes(true))
                return attribute.Identifier;

            throw new EntityException("No identifier has specified for this type of entity.");
        }
    }
}

Rock rock = new Rock();

// should print 1000
Console.WriteLine(rock.Identifier);
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the scenario.

Entity represents a 3D object. I'm writing a server software, that has a list of such entities. The server manually serializes the list and sends it to the client. As performance is highly important here, I'm not sending the type name. Every type of entity has a unique identifier, so when the client gets the data, it can efficiently deserialize it.

To create an instance of an entity, I'm doing something like:

```
Entity entity = EntityRepository.Instance.CreateNew(identifier);
```

The `EntityRepository` class looks like this:

```
public sealed class EntityRepository
{
    private static readonly Lazy<EntityRepository> lazy =
        new Lazy<EntityRepository>(() => new EntityRepository());

    IDictionary<ushort, Func<Entity>> _repo;

    private EntityRepository()
    {
        _repo = new Dictionary<ushort, Func<Entity>>();
    }

    public static EntityRepository Instance 
    { 
        get { return lazy.Value; } 
    }

    public Entity CreateNew(ushort id)
    {
        return _repo[id]();
    }

    public void Add<T>(ushort id)
        where T : Entity, new()
    {
        _repo.Add(id, new Func<Entity>(() =>
        {
            return new T();
        }));
    }
}
```

The current `Add<T>` method has a parameter that represents the identifier.

But how would I write a `Add<T>` method that has no parameters - that recognizes the identifier automatically?

So I was thinking about adding an attribute to the nested `Entity`:

```
[Identifier(1000)]
public class Rock : Entity { }
```

and a static property that returns the value of the `Identifier` attribute.

Then, an `Add<T>` method without parameters would look something like:

```
public void Add<T>(ushort id)
    where T : Entity, new()
{
    _repo.Add(T.Identifier, new Func<Entity>(() =>
    {
        return new T();
    }));
}
```

Note that in this case, I could just do `T.GetType()` to get the attribute, but that's not the point. How can I do that in the static property, `Entity.Identifier`?

Comment: What's the relationship between the `Identifier` attribute and the `Identifier` property?

Comment: I have edited the question to clarify this.

Comment: You say it's "not the point" that you could use `T.GetType()` (although you actually mean `typeof(T)`) - but if that sorts out your problem, why not use it? The way you were trying to do it simply won't work - so use a way that *does* work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't, basically.

A call to `Rock.Identifier` will be resolved by the compiler to `Entity.Identifier` - there simply isn't any context in which to find the type.

A call to `rock.Identifier` won't even compile, as you're trying to access a static member through a variable.

The best workaround would depend on the *real* scenario - in the case you've posted, I'd suggest creating a static method elsewhere which *accepted* a type as a parameter.

Actually, you could fake it in a really horrible way for your specific scenario by using the compile-time type of `Rock`:

```
public static class NastyExtensions
{
    public static ushort GetIdentifier<T>(this T actualValueIsIgnored)
    {
        Type type = typeof(T);
        ... code as before
    }
}
```

Then:

```
Rock rock = new Rock();
Console.WriteLine(rock.GetIdentifier());
```

But this would *not* be polymorphic. For example:

```
Entity rock = new Rock();
Console.WriteLine(rock.GetIdentifier()); // Bang! T would be Entity here
```

You could change the extension method to call `GetType()` of course...

Comment: "can't" is a bit harsh, you can (we both provide a way to do it), but there is probably a better way to get around the problem alltogether. In fact I have an extension method `T GetClassAttr<T>(this object o)` which I use in several places on code that is like this question.

Comment: I've edited the question with the real scenario. Maybe someone will come up with an idea?

Comment: @Bill: You can't do what was originally asked: get the "actual" type being used within a static member of a base class. There are workarounds to achieve "similar effects" but you can't get the type that a static member was called on.

Comment: Although not exactly what I wanted, I'll have to accept this answer as it is the most correct answer to the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

Static methods are *not* polymorphic in C# - there's no way for subclasses to override this implementation.

EDIT:
Essentially, as Jon Skeet points out, the C# compiler will treat a call to `SubType.StaticMember` as equivalent to to `BaseType.StaticMember` (unless of course the sub-type provides a *new*, hiding member with the same name). Consequently, this code will always run 'in the context' of the `Identifier` type, and there's no way to improve upon:

```
Type currentType = typeof(Identifier);
```

Personally, I don't like the fact that C# even lets you access static members 'through' subtypes - it just sets up nasty mistakes and misunderstandings.

Comment: Right. This means that the "current type" within `Identifier` will always be `Entity`.

Comment: Note that you can make use of this quirk of C# in that `SubType.StaticMember` will be compiled down to `BaseType.StaticMember` with generic type arguments specified. Thus if `BaseType` has a generic argument which you specify is the sub type you want, you can get the sub type in the method.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use generics:

```
[Identifier(1000)]
public class Rock : Entity<Rock> { }

public abstract class Entity<T>
{
    public static ushort Identifier
    {
        get
        {
            // How do I get here the current type of the object?
            Type currentType = typeof(T);

            foreach (IdentifierAttribute attribute in currentType.GetCustomAttributes(true))
                return attribute.Identifier;

            throw new EntityException("No identifier has specified for this type of entity.");
        }
    }
}
```

This way when you call `Rock.Identifier` the compiler will resolve it to be `Entity<Rock>.Identifier`. An example usage of this pattern is done in Castle ActiveRecord.

Comment: Or just make the method generic - probably cleaner.

Comment: This is a nice solution, but it doesn't make any sense :(

Comment: It would be great solution if constraints worked as they should, eg `Entity<T> where T : Entity<T>`. Sadly they don't work and errors like `class Foo : Entity<Bar>` are a nightmare to find. They work only in runtime type construction...

Comment: @Agent_L Actually, I got a `public abstract class PersistentObject<T> where T : PersistentObject<T>, new()` which works perfectly, and even allows statics that have that T as return type. I don't see your issue.

Comment: @Nyerguds Read my comment again. My rant was about the constraint not constraining enough. It works too well, because it works even where it shouldn't work.

Comment: @Agent_L I still don't see your issue... is there any reason why `class TextList : List<String>` shouldn't work? It just hardcodes the type rather than making it a user choice. They're just different use cases.

Comment: @Nyerguds because I put in the constraint that `T` must derive from `Entity<T>` - and it clearly does not in my Foo/Bar example. `List<T>` doesn't have the `where T: List<T>` so it's a different thing entirely.

Comment: Not sure what you're programming on, but the construction you showed indeed immediately gives an error on my Visual Studio: "The type 'Foo' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'Entity<T>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Foo' to 'Entity<Foo>'." You sure you're not talking about Java? Java is a total mess when it comes to generics.

Comment: @Nyerguds Try `class Foo : Entity<Foo>` and `class Bar : Entity<Foo>`.
Don't even start me about Java. Casting everything to Object doesn't count as "generics" : )

Comment: @Agent_L That seems perfectly legit. The restriction only counts for `Foo: Entity<Foo>`, and there it is correct. `Bar` just inherits that Entity<Foo> wholesale, and Foo obeys the restriction, but in itself, `Bar` is never used as `T` parameter for `Entity`. The restriction is only on `Entity<T>`, after all. There's nothing saying you can's then subclass that correctly filled-in `Entity<T>`.

Comment: On that note, this also doesn't imply it subclasses `Foo`. `Foo` may be restricted to being `Entity<Foo>`, but `Entity<Foo>` has no such restrictions the other way around; you can perfectly manually create a `new Entity<Foo>()` that isn't a `Foo`. If you want to avoid that... just make `Bar` subclass `Foo`.

Comment: @Nyerguds Well, it does not sound legit for me, as I expected `T` to stand for given type, not "any type". By this interpretation `Foo` obeys the restriction in `Foo` but not in `Bar`. And, as I said in the beginning, in dynamically constructed types, it DOES work as I expected, that is `class Bar : Entity<Foo>` is not possible. So, one of those must be wrong. Subclassing is a different thing entirely.

Answer (score 0):

`C#` doesn't support polymorphism for static members. Static members cannot be virtual or included in interfaces.
Thus you cannot easily group classes even when all of them have some static member with same name and signature.